# Расширение для Chrome. Создание нового таба при клике на иконку расширения

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Делаю расширение для Chrome. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике на иконку приложения справа, открывался новый таб с url "http://localhost". Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url : 'http://localhost'});
});
```